# validation only if a drop down value is not nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to perform a validation on a field only if a different field (a drop down) in the form is not nil.

my validation check if a phone number has 10 digits, is unique and presence only if the provider is not nil

```
validates :phoneNumber,length: {is: 10}, uniqueness: true, presence: true, if: "!provider.nil?"
```

my form

```
  <%= f.select :provider, options_for_select(%w[AT&T T-Mobile Verizon]), :prompt => "Select Cellular Provider",:selected => nil%>
```

no matter what I do this thing always performs the check of validation even if I did not select a value from my drop down.
According to the rails guide I can set selected to nil, and can perform an if validation
Any idea where am I getting this wrong?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After chatting with you I think you need, to continue validating length, presence and uniqueness, and in addition the case you mentioned:

```
validates :phoneNumber,length: {is: 10}, uniqueness: true, presence: true, if: lambda{ |record| record.provider.present? }

validates :provider, presence: true, if: lambda{ |record| record.phoneNumber.present? }
```

Comment: Nope still the same issue:\

Comment: checking the form values I see that 
 "provider"=>"", and not nil

Comment: can you post what are you getting in params from your server console?

Comment: replacing with present? just allow everything, so if I specify a phone number but not a provider it will let me create the user

Comment: <User id: 3, ..., phoneNumber: nil, provider: nil>,<User id: 4,..., phoneNumber: 1231231234, provider: nil>]>

Comment: I thought you wanted that, where do you want to validate? when provider is filled in? that's with `present?`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42708/discussion-between-quantico-and-juanpastas)